# custom email validating attribute not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I am creating custom email validation attribute, my code :

```
 public class EmailAttribute :  RegularExpressionAttribute
    {
        public EmailAttribute()
            : base("^[a-z0-9_\\+-]+(\\.[a-z0-9_\\+-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\\.[a-z0-9-]+)*\\.([a-z]{2,4})$")
        { }
    }
```

Now i put this attribute on an email property like :

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [Email(ErrorMessage = "Must be a valid Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
```

But this is not validating the email, `Required` attribute works fine but `Email` is not working. Can anybody please explain me why?

Comment: does the validation entirely not work or does it say "false" to all emails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server-side validation should work fine. I think you are talking about the client side validation and for that you have to `IClientValidatable` interface in the custom email attribute and also you have to create jquery adapter.

You can see an example [here](http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/4/model_validation_in_asp_net_mvc).

Answer (score 1):

When you calling the base() with your regexp you are setting the error message. Try use RegularExpressionAttribute for base class or with dropping your EmailAttribute class.

Comment: yep... totally wrong train... the constructor want's error-message...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute.aspx